# How to display multiple lines in a JTable Cell which is populated by query

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a jTable in which data populate by sql query....jTable have 15 columns...I want if any of the column reach the end of cell it shift to the next line of the cell(means multiline or wrap the text)...I have searched the sites but unfortunately don't get any result regarding jTable in which data populate by sql query

Comment: You could try using `JTextArea` for your renderer. It has a line wrap ability

Comment: Please focus on the core aspects of your question. Does it really matter HOW your table model gets filled? Isn't this SOLELY about how to render a table cell that uses multiple lines?

Comment: *I want if any of the column reach the end of cell it shift to the next line of the cell* - this is not easy. Yes you can use a JTextArea as the renderer for the cell. However you also need to set the row height for any cell that will wrap. Instead most people would just set the tooltip on the cell to display then entire text.